# Can I take a DIV or SPAN value and use it for Jquery plugin options?

Tags: jquery, twitter, html

I am using a twitter plugin that is being set with these options:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".tweet").tweet({
        username: "username",
        count: 3,
        template: "{avatar}{text}{time}",
        loading_text: "loading tweets..."
    });
});
```

And I have option values being rendered by a CMS that I would like to add to the options above.

For example:

```
<span class="twitteruser">{tag_twitter username}</span>
<span class="twittercount">{tag_tweets}</span>
```

Now the {tag_twitter username} will render whatever the user has added in the backend (same as tag_tweets). I would like to take those two values and add them into the username and count above.

Haven't managed to write anything remotely usable for this all day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".tweet").tweet({
        username     : $(".twitteruser").text(),
        count        : parseInt($(".twittercount").text()),
        template     : "{avatar}{text}{time}",
        loading_text : "loading tweets..."
    });
});
```